# What is the equivalent of auth in python in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm trying to access an api where I need to pass in the api key and the api secret but I'm doing it in Node JS.
In Python you can do this:

```
  requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'));
```

My question is how do I accomplish this in Node JS? Do I include the key and secret in the header or include it in the options object?

This is the code:

```
var options = {
  host:'linktowebsite',
  path:'/data',
  headers: {
' Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
});
res.on('end', () => {
 console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes,

```
var options = {
  host:'linktowebsite',
  path:'/data',
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization' : "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64")
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle)

```
const needle = require('needle');
let options = { username: 'user', password: 'pass' };
needle.get('https://api.github.com/user', options, (err, resp, body) => {
   // Whatever
})
```

[request](https://github.com/request/request)

```
const request = require('request');
request.get('https://api.github.com/user', (err, resp) => {
   // Whatever
}).auth('username', 'password', false);
```